# How to get the URL of an entity being created at hook_entity_insert() stage?

Tags: 8, entities, routes, emails

I'm trying to send an email "someone added content" with the URL to the entity as the message body.

```
function MYMODULE_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() === 'node') {
    switch ($entity->bundle()) {
      case 'contact':
        MYMODULE_mail_notify_admin($entity);
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_mail_notify_admin($entity) {
  $mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
  $module = 'MYMODULE';
  $key = 'contact';
  $to = 'secret@secret.com';
  # $to = \Drupal::currentUser()->getEmail();
  $params['message'] = $entity->toUrl()->getUri();
  $params['title'] = $entity->label;
  $langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
  $send = true;
```

The problem is that `$entity->toUrl()->getUri()` gives an error, "This URL has a Drupal route, so the canonical form is not a URI".

How do I get the URL from a URL object?  Is this a problem because the entity hasn't been created yet, and the route hasn't been assigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL object is there, you're just calling it wrong.

The code for this is a little complicated:

```
  $path = $entity->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString();
  $params['message'] = $path;
```

For more info, see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2722303).